# Nginx Preserve or Pass custome header after return 301

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have nginx which I am receiving http request then I will redirect them to https,

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     example.com;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com
    .
    .
    .
    location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://$backend_server;
 }
```

I have  2 custom header which named :

```
x_sub_ch1 
x_sub_ch2
```

I want to have them with proxy_pass , I have tried below but does not work, would you please let me know I can add these 2 custom header to proxy_pass:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     example.com;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com
    .
    .
    .
    location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

    # proxy_set_header X-Sub_Ch1          $http_x_sub_ch1; # this does not work
    # proxy_set_header X-Sub_Ch1          $http_x_sub_ch2; # this does not work

    proxy_set_header X-Sub_Ch1          $http_x-sub-ch1; # this does not work
    proxy_set_header X-Sub_Ch1          $http_x-sub-ch2; # this does not work

    proxy_pass http://$backend_server;
 }
```